# Equation with fractional power

Tags: analysis

How to solve for $x$ in this equation $x+\beta\, x^{\alpha} = y$, where $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>0$ are real numbers?

Comment: solve for $x$, $y$, $\alpha$,$\beta$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: _for $x$_

Comment: If $\alpha=2,3,4$, you have some formulas. Otherwise, numerically.